# how to look up hash_map in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap

Here's what I have, I am new to C++ so I am not sure if this is right...

```
typedef pair<string, int>:: make_pair;
hash_map <string, int> dict;
dict.insert(make_pair("apple", 5));
```

I want to give my hash_map "apple", and I want to get back 5. How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hash_map` is not standard C++ so you should check out the documentation of whatever library you're using (or at least tell us its name), but most likely this will work:

```
hash_map<string, int>::iterator i = dict.find("apple");

if (i == dict.end()) { /* Not found */ }
else { /* i->first will contain "apple", i->second will contain 5 */ }
```

Alternatively, if you know for sure that `"apple"` is in `dict`, you can also do: `dict["apple"]`. For example `cout << dict["apple"];` will print out 5.

Also, why the typedef in your code? Can't you just use `std::make_pair`? And, it won't compile the way you wrote it (with the two leading colons)

Comment: +1 If you *know* that `dict` contains apple, you can also use `dict["apple"]`. This can be slightly less efficient, but more clear in certain situations.

Comment: Presumably hash_map works like map, and if the key is not already present, it will add it with value 0. It does in the SGI hash_map, anyway.

Comment: @AndreasBonini Is it possible to do otherwise too, like `dict[5]` to get `apple`. If not, how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your hashmap, vector, list and other structures:

```
for(hash_map<string,int>::iterator i = dict.begin(); i != dict.end(); i++)
{
     cout << "key(string): " << i->first << ", value(int): " << i->second << endl;
}
```